# Android location based Augmented Reality values for sensors

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-sensors

I have created an augmented reality app. Now, I want to know which values are the appropriate for sensors? First of all the time interval between updates for the [gps](/questions/tagged/gps) is 30 secs and 3 meters. For the [accelerometer](/questions/tagged/accelerometer) and [magnometer](/questions/tagged/magnometer) the sensor delay in the beginning was normal -> UI and know it is game. which are the appropriate values for a good user experience. I tested recently the app and it wasn't too accurate. the icon was not exact in the building. Also I don't want to drain the user's battery. Most of all I don't know which sensor delay should I use.

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy depends on the accuracy of your current location. If your current location accuracy is within 10 meters then if affects for Point of Interstes as well. That's why you don't get the exact buildings marked. If the location that you are looking has a 3 meter accuracy and your current location accuracy is 5 meter, then the object that you are looking gets 8 meter accuracy only.